# Logout button for and Android App generated from Genexus for Smart Devices

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I'm working in a survey app in Genexus por Smart devices and I need to add a logout button. I've been trying with  `SDActions.Logout()` but when I build the solution apperas an error saying that this method is not implemented in Android.

I'm using Genexus Evolution 3 Update 2.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling `SDActions.Logout()`?

As currently implemented, it's supported in SDPanel or Dashboard user events, but not in Procedures or standard events such as `Start`, `Refresh`, or `Load`.

The error you quote would seem to suggest that is the cause of the problem. If not, I'd ask to please add more information (such as the exact error message and/or build output).

Comment: Thank you, I was using `SDActions.Logout()` inside a procedure I changed it to the Dashboard event and it worked perfectly.